# Alternative to groupby for the below mysql statement

Tags: mysql

I have a DB statement as below.how can i rewrite the following DB statement without using **group by** I mainly use groupBy in order to remove duplicate data from **tenantproperty** and **tenantentity**.

```
select * 
from app_mapping map 
where map.org = 'organization1' and map.entity = 'ALERT' and map.app_id = 66 and 
      map.mode = 'TENANT' 
GROUP BY map.tenantproperty, map.tenantentity;
```

Comment: A group by without aggregate functions is not a good thing generally.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is as follows:

```
SELECT DISTINCT columns
              , I 
              , actually
              , want
           FROM my_table
```